# clang/LLVM project level optimization

Tags: optimization, llvm, compiler-optimization, llvm-clang

So periodically I try LLVM as I have this theory it should outperform GNU.  And then it sadly doesn't.

Part of the theory has to do with its ability to link modules/objects together and THEN optimize, where normally optimization happens on a per file/object basis.

Instead of using a generic one, I see how to build for a specific default target

```
rm -rf llvm-project
git clone https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project.git
cd llvm-project
git checkout llvmorg-10.0.0
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS='clang;lld' -DCMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING=True -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/llvm/llvm10armv6m -DLLVM_DEFAULT_TARGET_TRIPLE=armv6m-none-eabi -DLLVM_TARGET_ARCH=ARM -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=ARM -G "Unix Makefiles" ../llvm
make -j 8
make -j 4
make
sudo make install
```

And the test files

test.c

```
unsigned int one ( void )
{
    return(1);
}
unsigned int two ( void );
unsigned int testone ( void )
{
    return(one());
}
unsigned int testtwo ( void )
{
    return(two());
}
```

two.c

```
unsigned int two ( void )
{
    return(2);
}
```

basic run

```
clang -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -c test.c -o test.o
llvm-objdump -D test.o

00000000 one:
       0: 01 20                         movs    r0, #1
       2: 70 47                         bx  lr

00000004 testone:
       4: 01 20                         movs    r0, #1
       6: 70 47                         bx  lr

00000008 testtwo:
       8: 80 b5                         push    {r7, lr}
       a: ff f7 fe ff                   bl  #-4
       e: 80 bd                         pop {r7, pc}
```

as one would expect, one() has been inlined into testone().

The desire is to get testwo() inlined as well.

```
clang -fomit-frame-pointer -c -emit-llvm test.c -o test.bc
clang -fomit-frame-pointer -c -emit-llvm two.c -o two.bc
llvm-link test.bc two.bc -o both.bc
llc both.bc -o both.s
cat both.s
opt -O2 both.bc -o both.opt.bc
llc both.opt.bc -o both.opt.s
cat both.opt.s
```

gives

```
testone:
    .fnstart
@ %bb.0:                                @ %entry
    .save   {r7, lr}
    push    {r7, lr}
    bl  one
    pop {r7, pc}


testtwo:
    .fnstart
@ %bb.0:                                @ %entry
    .save   {r7, lr}
    push    {r7, lr}
    bl  two
    pop {r7, pc}
```

and

```
testone:
    .fnstart
@ %bb.0:                                @ %entry
    .save   {r7, lr}
    push    {r7, lr}
    bl  one
    pop {r7, pc}

testtwo:
    .fnstart
@ %bb.0:                                @ %entry
    .save   {r7, lr}
    push    {r7, lr}
    bl  two
    pop {r7, pc}
```

that is worse.

```
opt -std-link-opts both.bc -o both.opt.bc
```

same, no better

Now this works

```
clang -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -c -emit-llvm test.c -o test.bc
clang -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -c -emit-llvm two.c -o two.bc
llvm-link test.bc two.bc -o both.bc
opt -O2 both.bc -o both.opt.bc
llc both.opt.bc -o both.opt.s
cat both.opt.s

testone:
    .fnstart
@ %bb.0:                                @ %entry
    movs    r0, #1
    bx  lr

testtwo:
    .fnstart
@ %bb.0:                                @ %entry
    movs    r0, #2
    bx  lr
```

One would think that not optimizing the parts would give more meat for the optimization of the whole to chew on.  Yes?  Although this indicates otherwise.

```
clang -fomit-frame-pointer -c -emit-llvm test.c -o test.bc
clang -fomit-frame-pointer -c -emit-llvm two.c -o two.bc
llvm-link test.bc two.bc -o both.bc
opt -O3 both.bc -o both.opt.bc
llc both.opt.bc -o both.opt.s
cat both.opt.s

testone:
    .fnstart
@ %bb.0:                                @ %entry
    .save   {r7, lr}
    push    {r7, lr}
    bl  one
    movs    r0, #1
    pop {r7, pc}

testtwo:
    .fnstart
@ %bb.0:                                @ %entry
    .save   {r7, lr}
    push    {r7, lr}
    bl  two
    movs    r0, #2
    pop {r7, pc}
```

-O3 doesn't help either, and this output is as pretty bad it calls the function AND inlines it.  What is going on there?!

```
llvm-dis both.opt.bc
cat both.opt.ll

; ModuleID = 'both.opt.bc'
source_filename = "llvm-link"
target datalayout = "e-m:e-p:32:32-Fi8-i64:64-v128:64:128-a:0:32-n32-S64"
target triple = "thumbv6m-none-unknown-eabi"

; Function Attrs: noinline nounwind optnone
define dso_local i32 @one() local_unnamed_addr #0 {
entry:
  ret i32 1
}

; Function Attrs: noinline nounwind optnone
define dso_local i32 @testone() local_unnamed_addr #0 {
entry:
  %call = call i32 @one()
  ret i32 1
}

; Function Attrs: noinline nounwind optnone
define dso_local i32 @testtwo() local_unnamed_addr #0 {
entry:
  %call = call i32 @two()
  ret i32 2
}

; Function Attrs: noinline nounwind optnone
define dso_local i32 @two() local_unnamed_addr #0 {
entry:
  ret i32 2
}
```

How does one undo that?

```
clang -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -c -emit-llvm test.c -o test.bc
clang -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -c -emit-llvm two.c -o two.bc
llvm-link test.bc two.bc -o both.bc
llvm-dis both.bc
cat both.ll
opt -O3 both.bc -o both.opt.bc
llvm-dis both.opt.bc
cat both.opt.ll
```

gives

```
; Function Attrs: norecurse nounwind readnone
define dso_local i32 @one() local_unnamed_addr #0 {
entry:
  ret i32 1
}

; Function Attrs: norecurse nounwind readnone
define dso_local i32 @testone() local_unnamed_addr #0 {
entry:
  ret i32 1
}

; Function Attrs: nounwind
define dso_local i32 @testtwo() local_unnamed_addr #1 {
entry:
  %call = tail call i32 @two() #2
  ret i32 %call
}

; Function Attrs: norecurse nounwind readnone
define dso_local i32 @two() local_unnamed_addr #0 {
entry:
  ret i32 2
}
```

and

```
; Function Attrs: norecurse nounwind readnone
define dso_local i32 @one() local_unnamed_addr #0 {
entry:
  ret i32 1
}

; Function Attrs: norecurse nounwind readnone
define dso_local i32 @testone() local_unnamed_addr #0 {
entry:
  ret i32 1
}

; Function Attrs: norecurse nounwind readnone
define dso_local i32 @testtwo() local_unnamed_addr #0 {
entry:
  ret i32 2
}

; Function Attrs: norecurse nounwind readnone
define dso_local i32 @two() local_unnamed_addr #0 {
entry:
  ret i32 2
}
```

So is it correct that you have to apply the optimizations everywhere, at the file/object level in order to get the project level to optimize?

And then there is the question of tail call or leaf, etc optimization, if nothing else testtwo: even in the first case

```
clang -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -c test.c -o test.o
```

could simply branch to two() and not setup a stack frame not do any of that.  Or is this a thumb thing? b cant reach?

```
one:
       0:   b8 01 00 00 00  movl    $1, %eax
       5:   c3  retq

testone:
      10:   b8 01 00 00 00  movl    $1, %eax
      15:   c3  retq

testtwo:
      20:   e9 00 00 00 00  jmp 0 <testtwo+5>
```

In gnu the linker patches up any branch reaching or mode issues with trampolines

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -O2 -mcpu=cortex-m0 test.c -o test.o
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D test.o

00000000 <one>:
   0:   2001        movs    r0, #1
   2:   4770        bx  lr

00000004 <testone>:
   4:   2001        movs    r0, #1
   6:   4770        bx  lr

00000008 <testtwo>:
   8:   b510        push    {r4, lr}
   a:   f7ff fffe   bl  0 <two>
   e:   bd10        pop {r4, pc}
```

Okay I stand corrected...

```
clang --version
clang version 10.0.0 (https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project.git d32170dbd5b0d54436537b6b75beaf44324e0c28)
Target: armv6m-none-unknown-eabi
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /opt/llvm/llvm10armv6m/bin

arm-none-eabi-gcc --version
arm-none-eabi-gcc (GCC) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I guess the question is if one wants to do a project level optimization using llvm-link and opt, is optimization of each of the individual items required or is there a command line option I am missing.  Not interested in compiler specific attributes that go into the source code itself, want the code infected with neither gcc nor llvm specifics.

After gcc 5.x.x the code got more bloated was hoping that llvm would have a chance but whenever I try this (on projects not just 10 lines of code) gcc ends up with fewer executed instructions, and/or fewer memory accesses, etc, etc.  For simple demonstration functions like the ones above, with some exceptions they produce the same/equivalent output.

Is there something, another one of the tools, or command line options, that I am missing in order to get more out of clang/llvm?

Is it that this is too trivial of an example for the tool to shine?

EDIT based on answer

```
clang -c start.s -o start.o
clang -O2 -flto=thin -fomit-frame-pointer -c test.c
clang -O2 -flto=thin -fomit-frame-pointer -c two.c
ld.lld start.o test.o two.o -o test.elf
llvm-objdump -D test.elf

000110fc testtwo:
   110fc: 02 20                         movs    r0, #2
   110fe: 70 47                         bx  lr

00011100 two:
   11100: 02 20                         movs    r0, #2
   11102: 70 47                         bx  lr
```

so getting rid of the -emit-llvm and using lto basically gives the desired result.

Looking at the bc disassembly

```
clang -O2 -flto=thin -fomit-frame-pointer -c test.c
llvm-dis test.o
cat test.o.ll

; Function Attrs: norecurse nounwind readnone
define dso_local i32 @one() local_unnamed_addr #0 {
entry:
  ret i32 1
}

; Function Attrs: norecurse nounwind readnone
define dso_local i32 @testone() local_unnamed_addr #0 {
entry:
  ret i32 1
}

; Function Attrs: nounwind
define dso_local i32 @testtwo() local_unnamed_addr #1 {
entry:
  %call = tail call i32 @two() #3
  ret i32 %call
}
```

enables/adds the tail call.  I really dislike using the compiler/shell as a linker (for embedded projects that have their own bootstrap and linker script), llvm-ldd usage wasn't easy to figure out or basically couldn't figure out, but ld.lld also supports the tlo stuff, so that worked out.

Comment: This does indeed not seem to be the kind of thing the LLVM developers talk much about, or focus on. What you have here is small and the optimisation is pointless in a sense — the program will be small and fast both with and without that change. You assume that LLVM doesn't inline in cases where it helps because you see that it doesn't inline in this case, which is... you may be right but I wouldn't bet on it. Try something very big instead, pick an optimisation that may help or hurt, and evaluate LLVM's choice of which sites receive the optimisation.

Comment: if it cant eliminate the call here then I wonder how it would do it for something more complicated.  but it does eliminate the call for some combination of command line options

Comment: There's a class that can inline, and the source code contains a comment saying "the decisions of which calls are profitable to inline are implemented elsewhere." That class is used in many locations. I didn't bother to look at the profttability assessment logic. Your call seems so unprofitable — one minimum-cost call, executed only once, no chance that inlining enables other optimisations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is pretty easy actually: one should never want to use llc / opt / llvm-link for performing "end-user" project level kind of optimizations. These are developer-side tools with different defaults, thresholds, etc. Basically, they are just simple command-line frontends to various pieces of LLVM toolbox.

In order to perform the proper link-time-optimization you'd need to use the pipelines that were intended for such task. Basically, compiling everything using "clang -flto" and then linking everything again via "clang -flto" would work. Using LTO-aware linker like lld is a prerequisite as well.

Some further information about ThinLTO could also be found here: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ThinLTO.html and http://blog.llvm.org/2016/06/thinlto-scalable-and-incremental-lto.html

Comment: Thank you edited answer based on what I found about LTO, basically clang -flto plus lto aware linker worked.